# Using generics in interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I have an app written in C#. My app has a class that looks like the following:

```
public class FinderA
{
  public IEnumerable<FinderA> GetItems()
  {
    return FinderA.FindAll();
  }
}
```

I want to require other classes to do something similar. I cannot use a base class because my actual implementation is already using a base class. For that reason, I want to create an interface. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
public interface IFinder
{
  IEnumerable<T> GetItems();
}
```

When I use this approach, I get a compile-time error that says: "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing...". To overcome this, I add `<T>` to the end of the interface name so it looks like this:

```
public interface IFinder<T>
{
  IEnumerable<T> GetItems();
}
```

This is turn generates another compile-time error that says: "Using the generic type 'IFinder' requires 1 type arguments.". My challenge is, I want the interface to be generic. I do not want to pass in a type. Is there a way around this? If so, what/how?

Comment: The request doesn't make any sense... You don't want to pass in a type but you want the interface to be generic. If your interface is generic, that means you have to pass in a type.

Comment: @TimothyShields He wants it to be inferred; specifically, he wants the generic argument to always be the type implementing the interface.  At least, that's what it looks like.  Of course, there is no such feature in C#.

Comment: a guess, based on how you defined FinderA: `public interface IFinder { IEnumerable<IFinder> GetItems(); }`

Comment: @Ash - Slick. That works perfectly for me.

Comment: @JQueryMobile If ASh's answer solves your problem, then you should reformulate your question

Comment: "I want to require other classes to do something similar." This could use some elaboration. The solution you seem to have accepted is a very strange one... without understanding your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around this; you'll need to actually supply the generic type argument when declaring that a class implements the interface.

Comment: Actually, the comment made by ASh above addressed my issue.

Comment: @JQueryMobile Well, that's not the question that you actually asked.  You asked if you need to supply the generic arguments to a generic interface, you do.  Had you described the actual problem that you have, we could help provide you with solutions to that problem, but you didn't actually do that in your question.

Comment: One individual seemed to understand it.

Comment: @JQueryMobile One individual guessed.  Lots of other individuals also made lots of guesses, and they were wrong.  Had you actually described your problem, instead of asking the question that you did, then you could have actually gotten answers that solved your problem, instead of answers to lots of very different problems, most of which you didn't actually have.  The person that guessed correctly didn't understand you any better than anyone else; he just made a lucky guess given woefully incomplete information.  This is why he commented, rather than posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your interface to be generic but you are not willing to supply a type argument, you can return an `IEnumerable<object>`.

```
public interface IFinder {
    IEnumerable<object> GetItems();
}
```

All class types extend from `System.Object` so that should suffice for any type in your applicacion (**enums** and **structs** would get boxed)

Please note that this approach requires the interface's consumer to cast the generic `object` instances to the appropiate types.

The alternate (and recommended) approach is to make the interface use **type parameters**, but for that you must supply the appropiate **type arguments**

Comment: Value types like `enum` and `struct`s would just get boxed.

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of generics. Also, value types *can* be returned, they would simply get boxed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at the method level instead of as a generic type on the interface itself.

```
public interface IFinder
{
  IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>();
}
```

Your code can then call it like such:

```
IFinder finder = // Create finder instance
IEnumerable<MyClass> discoveredClasses = finder.GetItems<MyClass>();
```

If you want to ensure that `MyClass` is a class that implements `IFinder`, you can constrain the method.

```
public interface IFinder
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>() where T : IFinder;
}
```

That will cause the following to generate a compiler error:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public class Bar
{
    Bar()
    {
        IFinder finder = // Create finder.
        // This fails because <T> (Foo) does not implement IFinder.
        IEnumerable<Foo> fooItems = finder.GetItems<Foo>();
    }
}
```

but it will allow the following to compile

```
public class MyFinderA : IFinder
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>() where T : IFinder
    {
        return // Create collection of T
}

public class Bar
{
    Bar()
    {
        IFinder finder = // Create finder.
        // This works as <T> (MyFinderA) is an IFinder implementation
        IEnumerable<MyFinderA> finderItems = finder.GetItems<MyFinderA>();
    }
}
```

Comment: But the methods that he has that should fulfill this contract *don't* vary in the return type, so the method isn't conceptually generic, the interface itself is.

Comment: He needs to show us a better example then. It sounds like this can be solved by adding a level of indirection on the interfaces if he wants to define objects concretely, then fetch them generically; I don't understand _how_ GetItems is used in practice given his example code.